# How to set name of file while upload as FileMetadata in dropbox

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

i the filename is always the folder name, how can i change it?
This is the code

```
public void uploadFile(String path, String foldername)
{
    String s;

    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
        if (path.length()>15)
            s=path.substring(0,16);
        else
            s=path;

        FileMetadata metadata = client.files().uploadBuilder(foldername).withAutorename(true).uploadAndFinish(in);

     }
     catch(...)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: I would like **s** to be name of the file in dropbox

Comment: When uploading to Dropbox via the Dropbox API, you specify the desired file name in the path value you give to the upload method, in this case the `uploadBuilder`. I.e., it takes the format "/file.ext" or "/foldername/file.ext". So, for example, to upload a file named "resume.docx" to a folder called "Documents", you would supply the value "/Documents/resume.docx".